SFTP: Pull files from remote host without directly knowing that they are there?
I'm sure someone has encountered a similar problem to mine before but I can't seem to find a solution by myself: There are two Debian hosts - one within a DMZ, the other within a secure environment. The host within the DMZ sometimes receives files from other hosts within the DMZ, then checks and sanitizes these files, and finally moves them to a download folder.
As soon as this has happened, the host within the secure environment should establish a SFTP connection to the host within the DMZ and download the files. However, the host in the secure environment should not directly "talk" to the host within the DMZ apart from the SFTP connection.
I'm currently struggling to find an adequate solution to this issue as I only see a cronjob as a tangible option. If possible, I'd like to move away from repeated time-based execution and instead implement some sort notification system that tells the host in the secure environment when files are ready to be pulled. Is there any way to pull this feat off?
I'm really grateful for any help regarding this issue.
